# Warning: "variable may be used uninitialized in this function" in a multi-mode structured function

Tags: c++, c

A multi-mode structured function may look like this:

```
void foo(int mode) {
    int opt_mode0;
    int opt_mode1;

    /* init section */
    switch (mode) {
    case 0:
        opt_mode0 = 3;
        break;
    case 1:
        opt_mode1 = 5;
        break;
    }

    /* shared execution section */
    bar();
    some_more_foo();

    /* distinguished execution section */
    switch (mode) {
    case 0:
         foo_mode0(opt_mod0); /* triggers warning of possible uninitialized opt_mod0. */
         break;
    case 1:
         foo_mode1(opt_mod1); /* triggers warning of possible uninitialized opt_mod1. */
         break;
    }

    /* more code here */
}
```

As you can see, the `mode` controls the mode, and all variables are perfectly initialized in their modes, but the compiler can not catch the logic to conclude that those variables are initialized.

Is there any clearer coding style/pattern to avoid the warnings?   Suppression this warning is not an option, as it disables the compiler to catch uninitialized variable bug for me.

Note that the example here is a miniature one.  A real function may be more complex.

Solutions for both C and C++ are welcome.

== Update: response to some comments ===

Please regard the example above as a miniature one.  So, some said to merge the two option modes:  Nope.  If mode 0 need 5 arguments, but mode 1 needs only 2, and they have different types?  Pre-initialize everything will then have the same effect as to suppress the warning: it will disable the compiler to capture the "use of uninitialized value" bug.

Comment: Why it is difficult to have them actually initialized to some value?

Comment: Just put initializers in your two declarations, like this: `int opt_mode0 = 0;` (and likewise for the other one). Pointless, I agree (if you're ***sure*** your code works as intended), but it will address the warning(s).

Comment: The compiler is right. There are execution paths that lead to `opt_mod0` not being initialized when it is used (as argument of function `foo_mode0()`).

Comment: If you just want the compiler to shut up, then just initialize the variables to some dummy value; `int opt_mode0 = -1;
    int opt_mode1 = -1;` would do.

Comment: *"Solutions for both C and C++ are welcome."* -- the C++ solution is to rewrite this code completely and split it into separate classes (based on the value of `mode`)

Comment: @axiac: if `mode==0`, the only execution path never sets or uses `opt_mod1`; if `mode==1`, the only execution path never set of uses `opt_mod0`; for any other value of `mode`, neither is set or used.

Comment: Why do you need two different `opt_mod` variables?

Comment: I'd have expected to compiler to complain about the switches' missing `default` cases in the 1st place.

Answer (score 2):

A C++ answer:

Use `std::optional<int>` for the type. Not only will the warning go away, but you can rely on the "not-set" status of the `optional` for the unset case.

A C answer:

Initialise the variables, disable the warning, or program a version of `std::optional<int>` for an `int` type; it's little more than a pointer really.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things you can do, all with their costs and benefits:

1. If possible, try to merge the section which are distinctly for only one mode. The spurious warning should disappear.

   Lifting the common parts into their own function(s) might further that.
2. If that's impossible, try contributing some more sophisticated analysis to the compiler.

   Everybody will benefit, but that's admittedly costly to you. And where do you draw the line?
3. Just give up and initialize it unconditionally. That sucks if doing so is expensive, and tooling will never again be potentially able to uncover related bugs there.
4. Just give up and live with the spurious warning.

   Most compilers provide easy ways to suppress specific warnings locally, look into it to keep your build quiet and warnings relevant.